# Spring Batch: How to get properties from subclass object from BeanWrapperFieldExtractor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have an application which takes xml as input and writing down to csv.

Here is my input xml:

```
<Main location="ABC" date="2018-02-26" name="Default">
  <Sub firstname="XYZ" lastname="PQR"/>
  <Sub firstname="147" lastname="123"/>
</Main>
```

I have below in my itemwriter's BeanWrapperFieldExtractor:

```
<beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
        <beans:property name="names" value="location,date,name"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

I'm getting correct output but I want to include **firstname and lastname** also and i have added below:

```
<beans:property name="names" value="location,date,name,sub.firstname,sub.lastname"/>
```

but I'm getting below Errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sub.firstname' of bean class [com.xyz.MainClass]: Bean property 'sub.firstname' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
```

Is there any way to extract whole Sub element from xml data of put in csv file one by one.

Comment: Could you show me the MainClass? It seems you don't have getter/setter as the error describe?

Comment: I do have getters and setters in MainClass, there is a Inner class which is Sub and in that also getters and setters are there for firstname and lastname.

Comment: If u can show more code, it is better for everyone

Comment: I have the same issue , did you solved that ?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, I have found two solutions to retrieve sub properties :

I assume you are mapping your input to its related classes.

**1.** Using the `FieldExtractor`, create a custom property + getter on your class to retrieve the child property :

```java
public class Example {

  @OneToOne
  private ChildExample childExample;

  // add Transient if you use hibernate to avoid validation:
  @Transient
  private String customProperty;

  // custom getter :
  public String getCustomProperty() {
    return childExample.getChildProperty();
  }
}
```

Then you can configure the `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor` on the writer :

```java
  BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Example> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
  fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"customProperty"});

  // then you configure the lineAggregator on a FileItemWriter :
  DelimitedLineAggregator<Example> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
  lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
  FlatFileItemWriter<Example> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
  writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
  writer.open(executionContext);
  ...
```

---

**2.** Using a custom `LineAggregator` and overriding the `toString` class method :

```java
@Component
public class ExampleLineAggregator<Example> implements LineAggregator<Example> {

  @Override
  public String aggregate(Example item) {
    return item.toString();
  }

}
```

Override the `toString` method:

```java
public class Example {

  @OneToOne
  private ChildExample childExample;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return childExample.getChildProperty();
  }
}
```

Then set the custom `LineAggregator` to the writer :

```java
  FlatFileItemWriter<Example> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
  writer.setLineAggregator(customLineAggregator);
```